# Nexus 5 multitask button not working after upgrade to Lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

I just upgraded to Android Lollipop on my Nexus 5 using the OTA update. For some reason, I don't seem to be able to use the multitask button. It works very rarely, but I'm having to revert to pressing Home then opening my apps from there. This never happened on KitKat.

Is this a known issue, and is there anything I can do about it? Restarting the phone doesn't seem to help.

The OS recognizes that I'm pressing the button, since it highlights and vibrates it.

On a related note, I've been having to tap the Home button twice for it to actually go the home screen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue has to do with the Tasker and/or Twilight apps.

I don't know why, but this is what solved my problem:

I rebooted into Safe Mode (press and hold the Power button until the "Power Off" text shows up), then hold that("Power Off" message displayed on the screen) down until it turns into "Reboot to Safe Mode".

After running in Safe Mode, I noticed that the Home and MultiTask buttons work correctly: ie. its very likely that an app is causing the issue.  I restarted the phone back to normal mode, and the buttons continued working.

I disabled Tasker and stopped Twilight, and the buttons began working as expected.  I've since re-enabled them both, and they both started working again perfectly, and the Home and Multi Task buttons work as well.

So either something was wrong with one of the apps, or just the act of turning on Safe Mode fixed something.